# разные действия при первом и втором клике на элемент - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Требуется выполнять разные действия при первом и втором клике на элемент.

При первом клике на строку (tr) устанавливается чекбокс и, если чекбокс установлен, код элемента добавляется в блок для вывода результатов.
Например, посетитель сайта добавил в "Выбранные" 5 строк таблицы (кликнув по ним).

При повторном клике на ту же строку чекбокс снимается, но нужно, чтобы код элемента НЕ добавлялся в блок результатов повторно.

Как можно выполнить другое действие при повторном клике на элемент?

В каких-то предыдущих версиях jQuery был метод toggle.

Как подобные вопросы решаются сейчас?

Код вкратце такой:

```
$('#table-flats tr').click(function(e){
  var tr = $(this).closest("tr").get(0).outerHTML;
  var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]')
  if(checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked")));
  else checkbox.prop("checked", checkbox.prop("checked"));

  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = tr;   
});
```

Comment: `if(checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.prop("checked")));` - ??

Comment: То есть, если клик произошел на строке, где уже есть чекбокс, оный снимается. Работает, во всяком случае. Хотя, я совсем новичок в jQuery. Может, и бред

Comment: А `if` тут зачем?

Comment: Подобие логики тут такое: Если клик произошел по строке, в первой ячейке которой нет чекбокса, оный устанавливается + html-код этой строки вписывается в блок результатов. Если в этой строке уже есть чекбокс, его нужно убрать и выполнить удаление html-кода этой строки из блока результатов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#table-flats tr').click(function(e) {
  ...

  if ($(this).data('clicked')) {
    // not the first click
  } else {
    // first click
    $(this).data('clicked', true);
  }
});
```